# Why this error surface for this loss function has negative values>

Tags: regression, machine-learning, linear-model, loss-functions

I'm studying linear regression in a Coursera course.

The author uses the following loss function in his examples:
[image]

And he shows the following error surface when he explains the gradient descent.
[image]

In this last picture, it seems that the cost function has negative values. However, mathematically, the loss function used by the author cannot generate negative values. Right?

I found this a little confusing. Can someone help me?

Comment: You're right; the sum of squares function cannot be negative. My Scientific Wild Butt Guess (SWAG): on the basis of the range of y values being between -3 and 3, the author of the visualization has standardized the loss function to have mean 0 and variance 1. A fact from optimization that may ease your confusion: if you take an objective function and multiply it by a positive number or
 add any number to it, you don't change where the optimum is. Therefore though the function visualized is not exactly the same as the algebraic expression, it is the same optim problem.

Comment: @JohnMadden That looks like an answer to me!

Comment: @Dave I'm not sure that it's actually the answer, because it's also possible that the author just took a random draw from a Gaussian process and is trying to pass it off as an algebraic cost function ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯. Would need a link to the course from OP to know more.

Comment: I agree: we cannot do any more than concur that the plot is not what it claims to be and guess what it might be.  *My* guess is that the surface really is non-negative (the pseudo 3D rendering makes it difficult to tell) and that it was generated arbitrarily as a schematic illustration.  I don't really believe the first part of this guess but I think the creator of this illustration believes it!

Answer (score 6):

> However, mathematically, the loss function used by the author cannot generate negative values. Right?

Correct. This loss function cannot be negative.

As mentioned in comments one possibility is that the author has standardised the function, hence arriving at a function that *does* take negative values. If that's the case, then it could be OK, since the location of the optimum should still be in the same place.

As also mentioned, there could be other reasons, so this is not a definitive answer.  I am just writing an answer for the sake of reducing the unanswered questions a little bit bit.